# How to multiply two columns from two different table with eloquent in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

**order**

- id
- currency_code
- ex_rate_with_base
- status
- total_in_base_currency
- status

**currency**

- currency_code
- symbol
- currency_name
- currency_value
- ex_rate_with_base
- status

**order_list**

- id
- order_id
- product_code
- qty
- unit_price_in_base_currency
- status

I want the following output:

Here I want to multiply the `ex_rate_with_base` field of **order** table with `unit_price` of **order_list** table using eloquent.

Comment: Do you have a little bit more to show us ? 
What have you done so far to try to achieve this ?

Comment: Can you add details aboute relationship among the tables please.

Comment: Have you defined your models and relationships?

Comment: @Sabyasachi Gosh, did you find a solution to your problem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can try this:

```
DB::table('order')
->select(DB::raw('(order.ex_rate_with_base * order_list.unit_price_in_base_currency) as orderRate'))
->leftjoin('order_list','order_list.order_id','=','order.id)
->get();
```

Hope this work for you !!!

Comment: @Sabyasachi Ghosh i hope my answer is help for you

Answer (score 1):

If you have Order and OrderList Eloquent Models, you can try something like this from a controller.

**YourOrderController.php**

```
$order= Order::find($orderId);
$orderList = OrderList::where('order_id',$orderId)->get();
$calculatedPrice = $orderList->unit_price_in_base_currency * $order->ex_rate_with_base;
```

Comment: It's not right to assume a specific relationship structure by OP especially since `order_list` is obviously a pivot table and not an entity table.

Comment: Based on what OP is showing, `order_list`is not a pivot table.
(It probably should but it's not)
And OP ask to use `order_list.unit_price_in_base_currency` and `order.ex_rate_with_base` using Eloquent. So...

Comment: Still you're assuming the classes `Order` and `OrderList` exist. OP seems to be refusing to answer whether or not they do exist which makes me a bit suspicious on what Eloquent models are actually there.